# JMeter : I am getting a response code 590. Why is it happening.

Tags: jmeter

I am creating a case for login. There are three HTTP Requests. After passing the parameters it should redirect to the home page of application. So i am getting the Response code 590 for 3rd HTTP Request where it has the path for Home page.
Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: Did you try with postman first?

Answer (score 0):

1. [HTTP Status Codes between 500 and 599 indicate server-side errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Server_error_responses) so first of all you should check server log - it should contain more information on the error you're getting.
2. It might be the case you have improper JMeter configuration. I would recommend simply capturing the requests which are being sent by JMeter and the real browser using a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)  - the requests should look **exactly the same** (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)). Once you figure out where the differences are - amend JMeter configuration, the main idea is that there should be no differences in requests.
3. Make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan - in some cases it's just a matter of missing or incorrect cookie, if you're lucky enough - it should be enough to resolve your issue.